# Escape pound or number sign in Github issue tracker

Tags: github, github-pages

If I type `#1` when creating an Issue in Github, it will reference to `Issue ID 1`. Is there a way to avoid this by escaping the `#` sign? I just need it to be regular text.

Comment: Why there isn't a sane escape mechanism for this is beyond me, is there some place to report this as a bug, I wonder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this `#1` and it worked.

Basically I have to escape by turning it into code quote

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. For example I'm not wanting to write code... often I need to describe something that should be pain text and don't want it to reference an issue.

Comment: Although it changes the formatting which might not be desired, at least it's pretty convenient.

Answer (score 106):

## short answer

choose from this list:

`#&#x2060;1`           ⯇ `#` — <**invisible character**> — `1`

`<span>#</span>1`

`<i>#</i>1`           ⯇ the number sign will be *italic*

`\# 1`

`#⁠1`           ⯇ you need to **copy-paste** this!

                     `#` — <**invisible character**> — `1`

                     even works for *commit messages*.

---

## more generic answer

These are the options you have:

- **Option A:** put any non-numeric (`[0-9]+`) UTF-8 character between `#` and the number

  - using the character itself (e.g. `# 1`) <sub>— this will even work in commit messages</sub>
  - using an [HTML entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) (e.g. `#&nbsp;1`) <sub>— useful for characters not on your keyboard</sub>
- **Option B:** use formatting on either `#` **or** the number

  - using Markdown (e.g. `#*1*`)
  - using HTML tag (e.g. `#<i>1</i>`)
  - **NOTE** that not all formatting variants, especially the Markdown ones, do always work!

---

## long answer

### 1    use a space character

You can put any kind of space character between `#` and the number.

#### 1.a    word joiner — `U+2060`

This is the most unobtrusive solution:

- `#&#x2060;1` ⇒ #⁠1

In this case the space character is written as `&#x2060;`, that's the [numeric character reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) for the `WORD JOINER` unicode character [[3](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf)].

The *word joiner* (WJ) is a **zero width non-breaking space**; that is, it's **not visible** (zero width) [[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)] and prevents `#` and the number from being separated by an automatic line break (**non-breaking**) [[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)].

#### 1.b    regular space — `U+0020` / no-break space — `U+00A0`

Of course you can use a "normal" space, which is faster to type than `&#x2060;`:

- `\# 1` ⇒ # 1

The backslash before the hash sign (`\#`) prevents the line from becoming a heading in case `\# 1` is at the beginning of the line.

The `\# 1` solution uses a *breaking* space. To use a non-breaking space, type instead: `#&nbsp;1` (no backslash needed).

#### 1.c    hint for advanced keyboard users

If you're using an [”advanced“ keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin-script_keyboard_layouts) such as [Colemak](https://colemak.com/) or [Neo (german)](http://neo-layout.org/), you can use it to type special spaces — non-breaking spaces (NBSP) and *narrow* non-breaking spaces (NNBSP).

- `\# 1` ⇒ # 1    (NBSP)
- `\# 1` ⇒ # 1    (NNBSP)

---

### 2    use formatting

Besides the solution of putting an extra character between `#` and the number, you can use markdown or HTML formatting. Below I'm providing some examples. Some solutions are striked out because they do not work (anymore).

*Please note* that the functionality could change at any time in case GitHub changes its code.

- using `<span>` (as stated by [Sam Harwell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532546/escape-pound-or-number-sign-in-github-issue-tracker/27394818#21649659))

  - `<span>#</span>1` ⇒ #1
- using italic font:

  - <strike>`*#*1` ⇒ *#*1</strike>
  - `<i>#</i>1` ⇒ *#*1
  - `#*1*` ⇒ #*1*
  - `#<i>1</i>` ⇒ #*1*
- using strong font:

  - <strike>`**#**1` ⇒ **#**1</strike>
  - `<b>#</b>1` ⇒ **#**1
  - `#**1**` ⇒ #**1**
  - `#<b>1</b>` ⇒ #**1**
- using single backticks:

  - `` `#1` `` ⇒ `#1`
  - `` `#`1 `` ⇒ `#`1
  - `` #`1` `` ⇒ #`1`

Answer (score 16):

You can use the following:

```
<span>#</span>1
```

I was quite surprised that the following did *not* work:

```
&#0035;1
```

Comment: @peterflynn Hmmm...just tried `<span>#</span>1` in a comment on Gist & Github, and it worked fine.

Comment: Can confirm both that span works perfectly and the HTML entity not working is surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested these and they seem to work:

```
<nav>#1
<section>#1
<section>#</section>1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully use the following...

`#&NoBreak;1`

...as in...

"My `#&NoBreak;1` concern is XYZ, and my `#&NoBreak;2` concern is LMNO."

...which appears like this...

"My #⁠1 concern is XYZ, and my #⁠2 concern is LMNO."

I discovered this by using Chrome's inspect on the invisible character in
[@myrdd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307637/myrdd)'s answer. Maybe that entity was not supported so long ago.

You can inspect just the same by right-clicking on #⁠1 above and selecting Chrome's inspect option... as mentioned, it shows the literal entity `&NoBreak;` in my browser's inspect pane.

Answer (score -2):

For me this `#_1` seems to work in github markdown.