# How to escape a '#' so it will NOT reference an issue in a GitHub comment?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

As opposed to [reference an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687262/link-to-the-issue-number-on-github-within-a-commit-message), I want to just output the text `#5` without any link. How can I do that?

For example, [a shader error message from Unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/5-0-1-standard-terrain-shader-fails-to-compile.317485/) could contain `#` and a followed
 number:

> Shader error in 'Nature/Terrain/Standard':
>   actual parameter #3 must be same type as formal out parameter ("weight")
>   actual parameter #4 must be same type as formal out parameter ("mixedDiffuse")
>   actual parameter #5 must be same type as formal out parameter ("mixedNormal")
>   too many parameters in function call at line 64 (on d3d9)

I have tried `\#5` and `&#35;5` but they don't work: still linked.

The question doesn't focus on how to escape `#`, but `#5`, which will be translated to a link to another issue. That's unexpected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape pound or number sign in Github issue tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532546/escape-pound-or-number-sign-in-github-issue-tracker)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could put an invisible character between the # and the number.

e.g.

`#&#8203;5` will be rendered as `#5` on GitHub.

`&#8203;` being the [unicode "zero width space" character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm).

Comment: That's a clever idea! :D

Comment: An invisible character will be picked up by cut-and-paste, which is not desirable.  An alternative is to write `<span>#</span>5`.

Comment: You should add this as a separate answer