# Github commit message escape "@" character

Tags: git, github

When I try to commit with a message containing the `@` sign, I always end up tagging an user.

Example:
In this [message](https://github.com/dev-marco/website-tester/commit/c1fe5d9a097ebdecebb236acba424d7b55a390e7), I'm referring to the `@property` python decorator, not the github user named "property".

Can I escape this character and avoid creating a link to an user?

Thanks

Comment: probably `\@` https://enterprise.github.com/downloads/en/markdown-cheatsheet.pdf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532546/escape-pound-or-number-sign-in-github-issue-tracker

Comment: tried both [here](https://github.com/dev-marco/sandbox-tests/commit/e4c6f223176cf8d94bc8a1ce72054c52b786d822), didn't work.

Comment: maybe there is a way to insert non-printing space character after @ `@&#8203;property`

Comment: @Slai [not yet](https://github.com/dev-marco/sandbox-tests/commit/d8d5f11b23966afb41fc1555a93f3e7ffda1edcc)

Comment: that was just a wild guess. I edited it a bit after to `@&#8203;property` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Comment: [Doesn't work](https://github.com/dev-marco/sandbox-tests/commit/f7f479087048d65f5c2b88191d16164d5c4345d1). I think github's commits message format doesn't accept these kinds of formatting, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120557/discussion-between-marco-and-slai). Stackoverflow complained that this discussion was getting big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to escape it.

Even if you try to use the escape sequence `\@` or wrap the content within a code tag ``` `` ```, it will still be rendered as `@mention`.

Here's two tests I tried:

```
$ git commit --allow-empty -m 'This is a \@test'
$ git commit --allow-empty -m 'This is a `@test`'
```

I also tried to use a longer commit message, and place the mention in the longer description. Once more, it did not escape it, neither with `\` nor with ``` `` ```.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do it, but it's a bit hacky. Slai was [very close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862079/github-commit-message-escape-character?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment65088279_38862079) to solving it. Instead of pasting the code for the zero width space, you need to paste the **actual** zero width space. [Here](https://github.com/nakamin/test-repo/commit/6cbebd6fff17694a5020c0c1f09854f2b6b96059) is a test commit that shows that it works.
Also [here](http://www.somebits.com/weblog/tech/zero-width-space.html) is some info about the zero width space character.

**Note:** The shortcut for Windows on the website does not work. It inserts ♂ instead.
**Note2:** Don't forget to thank Slai :)

Comment: We talked about it a lot in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120557/discussion-between-marco-and-slai) and came to the conclusion that this approach may show problems when copying / pasting the commit message from git website (imagine a case when a developer copies it to paste someplace where this character isn't supported), also it can break terminal text when using `git log` or similar

Answer (score 1):

There still doesn't seem to be a clear solution to this issue. What does work is something like this:

`@`Pattern

Only problem is that it shows a bit of white space between the @ and the word, but it might be an easier solution than remembering the unicode for a zero width white space.